# Control legends from multiple data frames simulataneously

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, legend

Is it possible to control the symbology of all legends contained in multiple data-frames (but on a single layout) simultaneously?

I want them to all have the same style, font etc.

Comment: Do the data frames and legends already exist already and you want to update them all? Have you looked into Arcpy?

Comment: Yes, they already exist. Just wanted to modify them but its turning into a nightmare. I've not looked into Arcpy for this.